# Ubuntu 12.04 no wlan0 interface

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, kernel

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer e5-571-31KM. Dmesg and lspci output indicate a wireless Network adapter was found, but according to ifconfig there is no wlan0 interface. Unfortunately I have no access to the machine right now, so I can't post the exact output, but I remember lspci gave me:

Network Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)

rfkill indicates that the wireless adapter is neither hard, nor soft blocked.

What I've tried so far:
- Reinstalling linux-firmware-nonfree
- installing the iwlwifi driver manually from this site 'http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi'

Both attempts didn't have any effect.

I'll have access to the computer this evening, so I will be able to post kernel version and exact outputs.

Do you have any ideas what to do?

Edit 1:

Here is lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics     Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI     mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI     Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

uname -r gives:

```
3.2.0-74-generic
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: maybe `ifconfig` is in conflict with `NetworkManager`? try to install and use `wpasupplicant`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't know exactly what you mean, but I'll give it a try asap. The wlan0 interface didn't show up in the gui, nor in iwconfig, etc. , if this is of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your relatively new device is not covered in the relatively old 12.04 kernel. I suggest you get a temporary internet connection. Open a terminal and run:

```
uname -r
```

Is your kernel version annotated '-pae'? If so, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic-pae
```

If not, do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic
```

Detach the ethernet and reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try it as soon as I have access to the mentioned machine (probably in 2 to 5 hours). What is the difference between the -pae and non -pae version? I read this advice in some other forum and tried it yesterday, but without any success. I didn't know the difference betwean -pae and the other version and simply installed some pae version. Do I have to reinstall the whole system in order to get back to the original kernel? And after I installed the new kernel do I have to change something in Grub in order to boot with the new kernel? Thank you very much !

Comment: PS: @chili555 I found an article concerning **Physical Address Extension** in Wikipedia. As the CPU supports 64bit, from my understanding (based on Wikipedia) there is thus no need for pae. I'll have access to the machine in 5 minutes, is there anything else (info) you need?

Comment: @schrankwand55 Nope. Please proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Installing the updated kernel worked for me. Keep up the good work, it's people like you who help to spread freedom. Thank you.

Comment: How can I mark the question as solved? It says I have to use a flag but flag gives me only the option to ask for a moderators attention? Thank you again! @chili555

Comment: Glad it's solved. You accepted the answer so that's all that's needed. Thanks.